# Indexing XML files with tags as fields

Tags: java, xml, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to index a bunch of XML files on my hard drive with Apache Lucene in Java. My idea was, for the best performance, to use the tags in the files as fields in the Lucene index, so when you search for a specific tag in a file (for example, an Ordernumber), the Lucene query would simply be `ordernumber:123`.

For example, I have this part of a file:

```
<contactPerson>
    <identification>
      <source>CUSTOMER</source>
      <sourceId>12345678</sourceId>
    </identification>
    <lastName>Vader</lastName>
    <firstName>Darth</firstName>
    <telefon>0000</telefon>
    <emailAddress>darth.vader@Imperium.com</emailAddress>
    <roleType>ORDERER</roleType>
  </contactPerson>
```

Is it now possible to index the XML file, so that I can use the query `lastname:Vader` to look for the last name? Would you recommend a better solution to search in XML files? Is there maybe an out-of-the-box feature I could use? Would it be easier if the XML files were stored in a database?

Also, later I will use Elasticsearch or Solr for the same task, but then the XML files will be in a database. What different options would be available when using one of these?